# Implementing Authorization Server with OAuth2 Device Profile Support

Tags: oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to implement an OAuth2 Authorization Server that supports the OAuth2 Device Profile. This is not in the final RFC, but was in drafts until 2010. You can find the draft here:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-recordon-oauth-v2-device-00

How can I leverage DotNetOpenAuth to accomplish this task? I am currently playing around with the AuthorizationServer sample, with little success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth hasn't claimed support for the device profile spec yet. While it *may* be possible for you to accomplish this using the library, it hasn't been done before to my knowledge. I suggest you [file a request](http://dotnetopenauth.uservoice.com/) for this feature